# How i supposed to show listView in fragment class with adapter from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

Hello i have this problem, i am new to this.I try to show my list in fragment. My app is running, but when i go to my fragment it crashes and shows This Error:

```
2021-01-08 14:27:25.442 13129-13129/com.example.parkngo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.parkngo, PID: 13129
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: For input string: "64.0dip"
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "64.0dip"
```

Apperanty error is in my Adapter class 17row whitch is this:

```
 val view : View = layoutInflater.inflate(id , null)
```

I've tried to look up information about viewGroups e.t.c

I have my created Adapter class here

```
package com.example.parkngo

class Adapter(context: Context, var id: Int, var list: List<Spots>):
     ArrayAdapter<Spots>(context,id,list){
          override fun getView(index: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
               val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
               val view : View = layoutInflater.inflate(id , null)

               val address : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
               val spotsLeft : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
               val time : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView3)

               var spotsList : Spots = this.list[index]

               address.text=spotsList.adress
               spotsLeft.text=spotsList.spotsLeft.toString()
                time.setText(spotsList.time)

        return super.getView(index, convertView, parent)
  }}
```

My fragment

```
class FreeSpotFragment : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var view: View = inflater.inflate(fragment_free_spot, container, false)
    var listview = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)

    var list = mutableListOf<Spots>()

        list.add(Spots("Zemitāna laukums", 9, 21))
        list.add(Spots("Brīvibas iela 78", 10, 21))
        list.add(Spots("Zvaigžņu iela 24", 9, 21))

    listview.adapter = Adapter(view.context, R.layout.row ,list)
    
    return view

     
}}
```

Here i will post my xml file for row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="307dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Parking spot adress"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Spots left"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textView2">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Avilable parking time"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textView3">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FreeSpotFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/freeSpotFragment"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    >

</ListView>


</FrameLayout>
```

I think my problem is in the fragment context. I probably don't have enough knowledge in this matter, but i've looked up many solutions, and try to study this..

Can someone explain my mistake here ?

Comment: can u please post your XML for row of listView

Comment: `Binary XML file line #53` ... There is something wrong in your layout at line 53

Comment: i updated Post.

Comment: please also post XML of your fragment

Comment: I think maybe you are passing the wrong `id` to your adapter class, because the error is having trouble with line 53, but the file you posted above has fewer than 53 lines. Or maybe you need to clean and rebuild your app if it has xml files mismatched.